# jave. Problem with extended class from jframe

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jframe

I have a problem when i try to create an extended class from jframe. When i add a panel to the created class with a specific dimension and position it will fill all the window. My code is:

```java
package tuto;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class test extends JFrame{

    public test(){
        super();
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 618);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);       
        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        add(panel);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    //Components
    JPanel panel;
}
```

After executing the code all the window become blue. Some help please.

Answer (score 0):

`JFrame` by default, uses a `BorderLayout`, which is why you component fills the full size of the window.  See [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details.

In fact, I'd recommend also reading through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to get a better understanding of how the layout management system.

You should beware that "manual" placement of components is generally discouraged in most cases, instead, you should make use of one or more layout managers.

As a general recommendations, you should also avoid extending from top level containers like `JFrame`, as it looks you into a single use case, top level containers tend to be complicated, compound components and you're just not adding any new functionality to the class generally.  Better to simply create them when you need them and fill them with the components you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use absolute positioning you should set the layout to null.

setLayout(null)

But it’s recommended you have a look at the different layouts. Everything is better than null layouts.

E.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html